# I want to run this flip coin animation continuously from on-create method.How to do it

Tags: android

Animation code is fine.But how to make it continuously. I tried thread but not working.This is my code. So please help me regarding this.I have tried thread and runonuithread() also but nothing working.I am trying this from two days.So please help me.

```
private ImageView image1;
private ImageView image2;
private boolean isFirstImage = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.review_users);
    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
    image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rotate();
}

public void rotate()
{
    if (isFirstImage) {
        applyRotation(0, 90);
        isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
    } else {
        applyRotation(0, -90);
        isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
    }
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                rotate();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

private void applyRotation(float start, float end) {
    final float centerX = image1.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    final float centerY = image1.getHeight() / 2.0f;
    final Flip3dAnimation rotation =
            new Flip3dAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY);
    rotation.setDuration(500);
    rotation.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(isFirstImage, image1, image2));
   if (isFirstImage)
    {
        image1.startAnimation(rotation);
    } else {
        image2.startAnimation(rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`handler`**

try

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isFirstImage) {
               applyRotation(0, 90);
               isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
            } else {
                applyRotation(0, -90);
                isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,500);//used 500s since your animation completes after 500s. 

        }
    };
task.run();
```

To stop this task, use

```
handler.removeCallbacks(task);
```